# ¿En PHP, cómo alternar dos colores de cada celda de una tabla según si es par o impar?

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo este código para crear una tabla, pero necesito ponerles color según sean par o impar, todos los pares de un color y de otro color los impares; creo que utiliza el if y else. Quizá se hace con CSS también.

```
<?php
$filas = 5;
$columnas = 3;
?>
<table border="1">
<?php for($y = 1; $y <= $filas; $y++) {?>
      <tr>
             <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $columnas; $x++) {?>
             <td> Texto </td>
             <?php } ?>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Es fácil con CSS

```
tr{
   background-color: #777;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres hacerlo mediante PHP: calcula las columnas pares y en base a eso cámbiale el color:

```
<?php
$filas = 5;
$columnas = 3;
?>
<table border="1">
<?php for($y = 1; $y <= $filas; $y++) {?>
      <tr>
             <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $columnas; $x++) {?>
                <?php 
                   if($x%2 == 0){
                       echo "<td style='background-color:#0f0'> Texto Par </td>";
                   }else{
                       echo "<td style='background-color:#00f'> Texto Impar </td>";
                   }
                ?>

             <?php } ?>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es posible hacerlo enteramente en css

Para filas impares

```
table.striped tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Para filas pares

```
table.striped tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #999999;
}
```

Para ponerlo en marcha solo necesitas:

```
 <table class="striped">
      ...
 </table>
```